# Why should not run Metasploitable on bridge network?

Tags: network, virtualization, metasploitable

I have read on somewhere that:

"Do not run Metasploitable (an Intended Vulnerable Virtual Machine)
in your **Bridge Network**."

Why? Does it create a bridge to the attacker's system directly? If yes, how does this happen?

Comment: I guess you mean "bridged" network adapter mode in Virtualbox. Say you run your PC in an untrusted network. Running it that way might expose vulnerable services of Metasploitable on your IP in the LAN. An attacker could infect the VM and use it for persistence / pivoting.

Comment: Do you know what a Bridge Network is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run Metasploitable bridged in your network, the VM is connected to the network directly. Everyone in the network has access to the VM so everyone can exploit the vulnerabilities.

The VM runs on your host so an attacker can use your resources. It could also be, that the attacker could escape the VM and attack your host device.

You should use a host only adapter to prevent this.

Comment: Or a NAT Network so different VMs can communicate with each other. Please see this answer for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/1095893/ipaddress-of-my-vm-doesnt-look-correct/1396375#answer-1396375